# Webpack error after upgrading to Angular 10

Tags: angular, webpack

I just performed an upgrade from Angular 6 to Angular 10 for our application. I have gone through various component and module TypeScript files, and have fixed any imports that became outdated, and weren't mapping correctly.

I kept getting an error when I would run ng serve that would say the following:

```
ERROR in Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

This would usually hang up in the terminal for a moment, then output file-specific errors underneath it.

I would fix those errors. Once it quit giving me them, I still get the same above error, with nothing underneath it. Something I did notice is that most errors involve angular dependencies transitioning from em2015 to esm2015.

I can run `ng serve --verbose=true` and get some additional output. It appears that something in webpack is hanging up the build process.

I have experienced numerous problems with @angular/dev-kit before and thought I could be experiencing more. I went ahead and did a clean uninstall re-install. Nothing different.

When I upgraded all dependencies in the application, I uninstalled everything, deleted the node_modules folder, force cleaned cache, and reinstalled everything.

Does anyone have any idea of what can be causing webpack to fail? I have attached my package.json, and the output of `ng serve --verbose=true`.

```
{
  "name": "ng-cosm-crm",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^23.2.1",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^23.2.1",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.0.8",
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.8",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/material": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^10.0.14",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.3.0",
    "accounting-js": "^1.1.1",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^23.2.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^23.2.1",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^23.2.1",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "^3.0.2",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "angular2-indexeddb": "^1.2.3",
    "angular2-logger": "^0.7.0",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.6.3",
    "angular2-tinymce": "^3.3.0",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "barcode-scanner": "0.0.2",
    "blend4web": "^18.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.18",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "currency-formatter": "^1.5.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "json-schema": "^0.2.5",
    "json-stringify-safe": "^5.0.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.1.0",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.9",
    "latest-version": "^5.1.0",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "mdbootstrap": "~4.19.1",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "ng-connection-service": "^1.0.4",
    "ng2-cache": "^0.2.1",
    "ng2-carouselamos": "^4.1.0",
    "ng2-chosen": "0.0.2-beta5",
    "ng2-select": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "2.0.0",
    "ngx-hm-carousel": "^1.7.2",
    "ngx-mask": "^10.0.1",
    "node-gyp": "^7.1.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.68",
    "pngjs3": "^5.1.10",
    "primeng": "^9.1.3",
    "quagga": "^0.12.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "6.6.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.6.2",
    "tinymce": "^5.4.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.1",
    "userpilot": "^1.1.7",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.6",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.14",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.2",
    "karma": "~5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1"
  }
}
```

I am running Node version 12.18.3 and NPM 6.14.6

Comment: Which _step_ of the upgrade failed? If you went all the way from 6 to 10 in one go (/commit) that's not what the [guidance](https://update.angular.io/) suggests

Comment: Jon, it looked like the actual upgrade of Angular/cli actually went well I watched it go from version to version with no issues. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: When you say *"with no issues"*, did you actually test each step? Or did you run through all of them *then* find out it broke at some point? It would be better to proceed stepwise (e.g. I recently did something similar, 6 to 10 - https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/commit/6dee52f65e570239955d4842158cb3944cd342b2, https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/commit/585b17facd67e54fac9f2465675b65728843f1d6, https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/commit/56974a4dc01b87774b020ef8da76794731b996f1, https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/commit/101b30fafac06d8f4955104e455eb5f0caf239a7).

Comment: I will double check the guidance that you linked, this seems to be more in depth than what I was looking at when performing the upgrade. Thank you for linking that. I will let you know if anything comes of this.

Comment: The definite elephant in the room was the RJXS upgrade. That seems to have been the only thing that didn't happen right. Consequently a lot of syntax across the application needs to be addressed. I will go through those errors and repost my success/failure

Comment: I have resolved additional errors when rjxs wasn't upgraded correctly. I still get the above mentioned error. ```ng update``` renders that all 87 project dependencies are up to date. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please give a [mre] of the specific upgrade step that's failing.

Comment: Jon, it was entirely to do with Rxjs not updating correctly. It did update correctly after following the official angular docs for migrating versions. Lot's of small things ended up being wrong in the application. I have got it working now successfully. Took about 2 days to clean everything up. Thank you for referring me to those documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This upgrade problem was entirely to do with rxjs not upgrading correctly. Once it correctly updated, I was able to get actual errors and go through them one by one to actually get the app to serve.

Do not miss the RXJS step of the Angular upgrade if you are jumping from rxjs 5 to 6!

The biggest time consuming element of this upgrade was rxjs itself. For example going from `.map().mergeMap().tap()` to `.pipe(map(), take()).subscribe()` etc.